# Form Validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hy!
I made a simple form and included my js validation file but it's not working.
I even included all the required scripts and css files but it's giving error.
The error on console is

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

I did not find any solution yet!

form_validation.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#contactForm')
        .formValidation({
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                name: {

                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The first name is required'
                        },
                    regexp: {
                      message: 'Name only contains Letter',
                      regexp: /^[A-Za-z]*$/
                    }

                    }
                },
                message: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The message is required'
                        },
                    }
                }

            }
        })

});
```

testForm.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/ecmascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/form_validation.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" id="contactForm" >
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="process"/>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am throwing a guess.
Please change the value of name attribute from this tag <input type="text" name="name"/>
Dont forget to change in form_validation.js as well..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the bootstrap flavour of formvalidation it makes certain assumptions about your mark up.

If you wrap your form controls in the bootstrap classes it should work.

Also, you're refencing a message field in your javascript which is not present in your markup.

Try something like this:

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" >

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
   <div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="message" id="message"/>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="process"/>

</form>
```

Comment: I know that by adding bootstrap classes, it would work but what if i want to run the same validation on core php?

Comment: Then you're using the wrong library. Formvalidation works with Bootstrap, Foundation, Pure, Semantic or UIKit. If you want to use it without any of those frameworks you would probably be better off using jquery-validation or something of the sort. You could also roll your own, but it might require some work. Have a look here if you're interested in going down that path: http://formvalidation.io/examples/#supporting-other-frameworks-and-form-builders

Comment: Thanks dear .
God Bless you